# is not clicked in html using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery, I have a problem. I want to check the not condition on html element using jquery, like this, any help will be awesome

```
if(("#id")!clicked())
{  
     alert("must clicked");
     return;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to check - what is id, a link? Do you mean clicked as part of this event, or clicked since the page loaded, or something else? Or is it a checkbox or a radio button or similar?

Comment: its an image <img> placed in html, i want that user must click on it.

Answer (score 2):

not to sure what you're after but try this. Add an onclick attribute to the you element and the below js.

html:

```
<img src="abc.jpg" onclick="is_clicked=true;" />
```

js:

```
var is_clicked = false;

... you code here ...

if(!is_clicked) {  
    alert("must clicked");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you rework on your solution.

I am sure we can check that this element was clicked/checked in better ways. If it is dropdown, we can test if any valid value is selected. If it is a checkbox then we can test if it is checked.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't think you would be able to check if you can check if image element was clicked or not .... please if anyone does improve me!!

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery."></script>
<script>
var flag = false;

function click(){
    flag =  true;
}

function check(){
    if(flag == false)
    {
        alert("Image was not clicked");
    }
    else{
        alert("Image was clicked");
    }
}

</script>

<img id="img" src="http://a7.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash1/hs744.ash1/163661_10150382342455319_722950318_17002228_7386702_n.jpg" onclick="click()"></img>
<input type="button" onclick="javascript: check()" value="check"/>
```

Comment: thnxs dude :) really thanxs :)